# How to take tuple as an argument and returns a tuple consisting of the first three and the last three elements of the argument

Tags: python, function, tuples

In a function, I need to return a tuple consisting the first 3 and last 3 elements of the argument. I have tried the min and max but i need to get (10,20,30,70,80,90)

so for example:

if the function is called with the tuple (0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90) as argument, the function supposed to return (10,20,30,70,80,90). Can someone please explain to me or give me a hint on what should I do?

this is my current code:

```
def first3_last3(t):
    return min(t), max(t)


t = (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
print(first3_last3(t))
```

Comment: if you sort the input to your function, than you can use slicing, `[:3]`, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the splat operator `*` to merge the sliced tuples:

```
def first3_last3(t):
    return (*t[:3], *t[-3:])

t = (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
print(first3_last3(t))
```

Output:

```
>> (10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorting (if it's unsorted) and using slicing gives you the output you are looking for.

```
def first3_last3(t):
    t = sorted(t)
    return tuple(t[:3] + t[-3:])


t = (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
print(first3_last3(t))
```

returns

```
(10, 20, 30, 70, 80, 90)
```